# How to configure Ingress request timeouts on GKE

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I currently have an Ingress configured on GKE (k8s 1.2) to forward requests towards my application's pods. I have a request which can take a long time (**30** seconds) and timeout from my application (504). I observe that when doing so the response that i receive is not my own 504 but a 502 from what looks like the Google Loadbalancer after **60** seconds.

I have played around with different status codes and durations, exactly after 30 seconds i start receiving this weird behaviour regardless of statuscode emitted.

Anybody have a clue how i can fix this? Is there a way to reconfigure this behaviour?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

When creating an ingress on GKE the default setup is that a GLBC HTTP load balancer will be created with the backends that you supplied. Default it is configured at a 30 second timeout for your application to handle the request.

If you need a longer timeout you have to edit this manually after setup in the backends of your [HTTP Load balancer](https://console.cloud.google.com/net-services/loadbalancing) in the google cloud console.

[image]

Comment: Yes the controller tries to pick sensible defaults. Timeout > 30s is not something that's been asked for, so I just dropped it from beta. If it's something you need often I can push it through as an annotation on the Ingress itself.

Comment: @PrashanthB We do have a need to configure the timeout and would appreciate it if it were configurable via annotation

Answer (score 32):

Beginning with 1.11.3-gke.18, it is possible to configure timeout settings in kubernetes directly.

First add a backendConfig:

```yaml
# For GKE < 1.16.8-gke.3 use "cloud.google.com/v1beta1" below
apiVersion: cloud.google.com/v1
kind: BackendConfig
metadata:
  name: my-bsc-backendconfig
spec:
  timeoutSec: 40
```

Then add an annotation in Service to use this backendConfig:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-bsc-service
  labels:
    purpose: bsc-config-demo
  annotations:
   # For GKE < 1.16.8-gke.3 use "beta.cloud.google.com/backend-config" below 
   cloud.google.com/backend-config: '{"default": "my-bsc-backendconfig"}'
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    purpose: bsc-config-demo
  ports:
    - port: 80
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 8080
```

And voila, your ingress load balancer now has a timeout of 40 seconds instead of the default 30 seconds.

See https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/configure-backend-service#creating_a_backendconfig

Comment: I don't understand: where does the `backendConfig` go? I mean, is it in a separate file?

Comment: @pietro909 it can be in its own yaml file or in a yaml file together with other resources. See https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/manage-deployment/

Comment: it's also possible to associate a backend-config with all ports on the service with an annotation like this: cloud.google.com/backend-config: '{"default": "my-backendconfig"}' (see https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/ingress-features#associating_backendconfig_with_your_ingress)