# Long requests (14 minutes) to REST API server on Kubernetes never return, no error, no nothing. Works on local docker

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, gke-networking

I am facing a strange issue while running my REST API server on Kubernetes. The requests that take a long time to complete, e.g. a 14-minute request, never return while everything works fine when I run the same Docker image locally or for shorter requests (5 minutes) on kubernetes.

I have confirmed that the server finishes the request, and that return is being called. However, the client never receives anything, and it just keeps waiting for a response forever.

The server has a timeout set to more than half an hour, so it shouldn't be a timeout issue. The client uses Python's requests library with no timeout set, so considering that nothing is returned, the client freezing and waiting forever is expected behavior. I could set a timeout, but that nothing is returned is still my main problem here.

I have checked the logs of both the pod and the ingress, but they don't indicate any error.

Although the server and client seem to work correctly, there seems to be an issue with the parts in between when using Kubernetes - but not when using Docker on a local system.

As for my implementation, I am using a Python Flask and Gunicorn-based REST server as a regular Deployment in Kubernetes, nothing fancy is done here. This Deployment is connected to a NodePort service that remaps the ports from 5000 to 80 and adds a backend config, increasing timeouts to 2700 seconds. The service is accessed through an Ingress that uses [name-based virtual hosting](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#name-based-virtual-hosting) and adds HTTPS to requests. Everything is hosted on Google using an [Autopilot](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/autopilot-overview) cluster.

Can someone help me with this issue?

Comment: Did you override Ingress timeout ? I think default value is short 30s or 60s.

Comment: @Mr_Thorynque I did set a backend config for this backend, but didn't do anything specific to the ingress. What I did seems to work though, as requests don't time out even after 5 minutes. Even the failing requests don't seem to timeout as there is no such error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36200528/how-to-configure-ingress-request-timeouts-on-gke the second response using GLBC HTTP load balancer. Maybe you will have log/informaiton on HTTP load balancer.

Comment: I see the timeout I set (more than half an hour) there. It's a bit hard for me to understand what it belongs to because some services have "default-my-service" as part of their name and this one doesn't, but there really isn't any other service it could belong to either.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a close look on what route your HTTP requests go before they reach the destination service inside Kubernetes. Timeouts could happen in firewalls, reverse proxies, etc.

I encountered a similar problem recently and in my case the timeout happened in the ingress. My ingress was nginx and if you don't specify something manually, nginx uses 60 seconds as default timeout.

My service deployment was done with HELM and there I had to add these annotations in order to increase the timeout to 120 seconds:

```
ingress:
  enabled: true
  annotations: 
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-connect-timeout: '120'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: '120'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: '120'
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
```

Depending on how you deploy your service and what kind of ingress you use, you could try to set something similar and increase values accordingly.

*Note:*

From my personal experience such long lasting requests are not good and you should probably also think about redesigning your API. If a request needs 14 minutes today, you never know if it might need an hour later, when there is more data to process, etc. So it is difficult to set a good timeout.

An alternative could be to use asynchronous handling, like a first request, which starts the action and a second one, which can request the result and try again later, if the result is not ready.

Or you implement this call with Web Sockets, so that the server can send back a message to the client, once processing is done.