# How to configure service request timeout on GKE using backend Config metadata annotation

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a service that uses SSE and therefore requires a long-living connection. I attempted to use the "cloud.google.com/backend-config" annotation to specify my back-end config but I keep getting an error indicating that the label is invalid. The error I receive is:

metadata.labels: Invalid value: "\{"default": "my-backendconfig"\}": a valid label must be an empty string or consist of alphanumeric characters, '-', '*' or '.', and must start and end with an alphanumeric character (e.g. 'MyValue',  or 'my_value',  or '12345', regex used for validation is '(([A-Za-z0-9][-A-Za-z0-9*.]*)?[A-Za-z0-9])?')

The value I am attempting to use is almost the exact same value I have seen in multiple examples including one from stack overflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36200528/how-to-configure-ingress-request-timeouts-on-gke)

Here is the exact annotation I am using:

```
cloud.google.com/backend-config: '{"default": "my-backendconfig"}'
```

Note that I get this error when using my helm chart deployment as well as trying to manually update the service via the GKE console.

I am using version 1.25.10-gke.1200

I have tried to escape the brackets as well but of course this didn't help. As mentioned, I originally added this change to my helm chart and when I received the error I thought maybe helm didn't support these type of values. I then tried to update my currently deployed service directly in the Google Cloud admin console and I get the same error.

The backend config appears to be deployed successfully although based on the error I don't think  the service is getting that far down the road.  When I describe the backend config I see:

```
Name:         my-backendconfig
Namespace:    ***
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>
API Version:  cloud.google.com/v1
Kind:         BackendConfig
Metadata:
  Creation Timestamp:  2023-08-14T14:41:51Z
  Generation:          1
  Resource Version:    865340930
  UID:                 ***
Spec:
  Connection Draining:
    Draining Timeout Sec:  1800
  Timeout Sec:             1800
Events:                    <none>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this was just a plain silly mistake. I had the annotation in the wrong place. The annotation was getting generated in the "label" section instead of "annotations". Of course labels can only be text, thus the parsing error.